# Filter elements from list based on them containing spam terms

Tags: python, filter, scraper

So I've made a script that scrapes some sites and builds a list of results. Each result has the following structure:

```
result = {'id': id,
            'name': name,
            'url': url,
            'datetime': datetime,
        }
```

I want to filter results from the list of results based on spam terms being in the name. I've defined the following function, and it seems to filter certain results, but not all of them:

```
def filterSpamGigsList(theList):
    index = 0
    spamTerms = ['paid','hire','work','review','survey',
                 'home','rent','cash','pay','flex',
                 'facebook','sex','$$$','boss','secretary',
                 'loan','supplemental','income','sales',
                 'dollars','money']
    for i in theList:
        for y in spamTerms:
            if y in i['name'].lower():
                theList.pop(index)
                break        
            index += 1
    return theList
```

Any clue why this might not be filtering out all results that contain these spam terms? Maybe I need to call .split() on name after calling .lower() as some of the names are phrases?

Comment: You are modifying `theList` in-place while iterating over it. Does changing the line `for i in theList:` to `for i in theList[:]:` help? `theList[:]` basically makes a copy of the list.

Comment: i think you can achieve that in single for loop... for i in results:
    if i['name'].lower() in spamTerms:
        print i

Comment: @Jakub That makes a lot of sense! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you've got a problem with in-place modifying theList as iterating over it as Jakub suggested.

The obious way would be to return a new list. I would split this in two functions for readability:

```
def is_spam(value):
    spam_terms = ['paid','hire','work','review','survey',
                 'home','rent','cash','pay','flex',
                 'facebook','sex','$$$','boss','secretary',
                 'loan','supplemental','income','sales',
                 'dollars','money']
    for term in spam_terms:
        if term in value.lower():
            return True
    return False

def filter_spam_gigs_list(results):
    return [i for i in results if not is_spam(i['name'])]
```

Comment: Hey Konrad, thanks for this as I really like the form of your solution. That said, I tried it out and it only seemed to be working to filter out results with 'paid' in them. 


I think this was due to your return False usage. 


Instead of returning True or False mid function, I used setSpam = False at the beginning of the function, then within the if term in value.lower() check, would do setSpam = True, then returned setSpam at the end. This appears to be filtering things appropriately.

Comment: Hi! Glad to be helpful. I'm quite surprised with your problems though. I've just copied my solution to Python 2.7.11 and Python 3.4.4 Idle and it works like a charm.
For list result = [{'id' : 1, 'name' : 'sex stuff'}, {'id' : 2, 'name' : 'good one'}, {'id' : 3, 'name' : 'paid'}, {'id' : 4, 'name' : 'maybe you want to rent a car'}] it returned only the 'good one'...